# Difference between save and save_model()

Tags: django

For all of my Django needs that overriding the save method requires, I've been using `save()` in my models. All the sudden when I was looking up something that required a little extra flare, someone suggested overriding `save_model()` in my admin class.

I found the docs on both, and I noticed right away that the arguments are different. 
Is `save_model()` only called when the model is saved from the admin? and the `save()` method is called whenever the model is saved?

UPDATE

So I've figured out that when saving from the admin. Both 'save' and 'save_model()' get called. It appears that 'save_model()' gets called first. In my specific application, I am using pre_save signals, and 'save()' overrides. Now I want to add in 'save_model()'overrides . It's the interaction and order of all of these save overrides and signals that is confusing me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `save()` is a method of `Model` whereas `save_model()` is a method of `ModelAdmin`... yes.

Comment: Okay, I know that. But what are the fundamental differences? why do both exist? When is one called as compared to the other?

Comment: and if you're saving from the admin.. what is called first? save_model() or save()?

Comment: One exists so that admin-specific/-only rules can be implemented, and the other exists so that rules that affect all uses of a model can be implemented.

Comment: So if I need both functionalities (save and save_model()). and a pre_save signal going out. How do I figure out order of operations?

Comment: The signal is triggered when `Model.save()` is called. `ModelAdmin.save_model()` eventually calls the `save()` method on the model.

Comment: Thank you. I think that clarifies it. Now to figure out how to get all of these save things working together.