# Call a method for each model instance

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Category` model. I want to make a directory for the category everytime I create a new category. I have a method in my model called `create_directory`.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="category")
    category_description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, default=1)

    def create_directory(self):
        gallery_path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, Category.slug))
        if not os.path.isdir(gallery_path):
            os.mkdir(gallery_path)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        unique_together = ("category_title", "slug")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title
```

I want to call `create_directory` each time I create a category in the Admin panel.

Comment: Write your create directory logic in save method of models. And save method gets called when you create the object of model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you meant `self.slug` and not `Category.slug`.  `self.slug` is the value of the slug field for *that particular instance*, while `Category.slug` is just an instance of the `SlugField` class.

You should override your model's `save` method to call `create_directory`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

    def create_directory(self):
        gallery_path = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        if not os.path.isdir(gallery_path):
            os.mkdir(gallery_path)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.create_directory()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively, you can create a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) for this:

models.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Category)
def category_post_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    gallery_path = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, instance.slug))
    if not os.path.isdir(gallery_path):
        os.mkdir(gallery_path)
```

### Update

If you want to remove the directory as well, you can override the `delete` method:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    ...

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

There is also a [`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#pre-delete) signal that you can use.

Comment: I would add a little `if` before the `create_directory()`-call to just call it on the initial creation: `if not self.pk`. (`super().save(...)` needs to be called afterwards then). If this is not present, it gets called every time you create **and change** an instance.

Comment: @wfehr good point I didn't think of that.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks this works however what if I delete a category from the admin panel? How can I handle for that?

Comment: @GTA.sprx you might want to take a look at the `delete()` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects

Comment: @GTA.sprx I added an update for that.  Note that the directory *must be empty* for `os.rmdir` to work.

Comment: @CalebGoodman Thanks. I noticed it doesn't delete if I choose `delete selected categories` I have to actually go to edit the category then choose `Delete` I also replaced `os.rmdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))` with `shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.slug))`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to call create_directory each time I create a category in the Admin panel.

As you want to call the `create_directory` method when a category is created from the `admin panel`, you should use [save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) and not [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save).

You might want to read [Difference between save() and save_model()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975392/difference-between-save-and-save-model).

Simply you can do:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    self.create_directory()
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```